# Adding Typescript to JS project - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an existing JS project (node, apollo-server, sequelize) and want to add (eventually replace with) Typescript. I installed the package(s) and added the `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "checkJs": false,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I then created a Typescript file that does some imports. And I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. All the js files are using `require`. And I'm using `require` to import the TS file into a JS file. I've done a bunch of googling but nothing I've tried so far has worked.

Comment: Try changing the `target` property of tsconfig.json to `commonjs` instead of `esnext`.

Comment: @EpicPuppy613 ya, I've tried that. Didn't do the trick. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I shouldn't have to ask a trusted user for this, but: please give a [mre]. @EpicPuppy613 that would be a `module` not a `target`.

Comment: Try setting it to ES5 instead of ESNext then.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I understand that would be ideal. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @EpicPuppy613 I've tried that as well. :)

Comment: You're trying to mix old-style CommonJS module management with ES module syntax. The two are not compatible (well without some effort).

Comment: @EpicPuppy613 this isn't how `target` works - the module system is separate from the language level, _that's
why there's a `module` setting_.

Comment: @Pointy I am learning that. LOL.

Comment: Not so much ideal as more-or-less mandatory, we can't do much without it! Most likely you're trying to use a third-party library that's an ES module; TypeScript will make all of _your_ code CommonJS as requested.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm gonna answer my own question since I put the pieces together. In addition to typical TypeScript config, I had to...

- Install `ts-node` for `devDependencies`
- `tsconfig` should have module as CommonJS.
- `package.json` should NOT have type as module
- create `nodemon.json`, mine looks like this:

```
{
  "watch": ["src", "config"],
  "ext": "ts,json,js",
  "exec": "ts-node server.js"
}
```

Now it works.